# Use data-attribute in HTML for image instead of javascript editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I broke my head trying to find the correct way to solve my problem. I have the following code for my sticky Header.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  
    {
        $('.sticky-navbar').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.sticky-navbar').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','assets/images/logo-sticky.png');
    } else {
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','assets/images/logo.png')
    }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<html>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top sticky-navbar hideme visible animated fadeInDown full-visible">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right custom-pull">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to add to my image tag `<img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt=""></a>` a data attribute, something like that `<img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" data-sticky-logo="assets/images/logo-sticky.png"></a>` so when the user scroll down and the `.sticky-navbar` class appears the logo changes to `assets/images/logo-sticky.png`.

Does it make sense?

Comment: If the idea is to switch the data-sticky and the src, you can do that. Then again, if all image pairs are called x and x-sticky, you can just add"-sticky" to the current src of the image and have no need for the data attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No the idea is to remove the URLs from javascript code and show the sticky logo instead of regular logo when the user scroll down.

Comment: Hence, will you switch around the data-sticky and the src when the user scrolls down? So the javascript will just be like `$('.navbar-brand img').attr('src', $('.navbar-brand img').attr('data-sticky'));` Or are you going to use CSS to detect when to use data-sticky or src ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. If I got it right I add a .sticky-navbar class (with jQuery) when the user scrolls and as soon as the class appeared want the regular logo switch to its sticky version with data-sticky-logo attribute, where I can change its name, path etc in my index.html file, not in javascript. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok. I did not understand either. I did not know JQuery can do that. So just ignore my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a `data-sticky` attribute to your image element. This will be
   the value to be updated on the image when you choose to apply it.
2. Initially store the default image src value for reversal
3. Toggle `.sticky` class & image src on scroll

So your image will look like:

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" data-sticky="assets/images/logo-sticky.png" />
```

And your JS:

```
// Initially set the original src
var navbarImg = $('.navbar-brand > img')
navbarImg.data('original', navbarImg.attr('src'))

// Update on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var stickyNav = $('.sticky-navbar');
    var isSticky = $(this).scrollTop() > 50;
    stickyNav.toggleClass('sticky', isSticky);
    navbarImg.attr('src', navbarImg.data(isSticky ? 'sticky' : 'original'));
});
```

Comment: That's a brilliant solution! Works perfectly for me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to toggle image logo based on scroll height:
you can store the links in data attributes like:

```
<img src="" alt="" data-logo="assets/images/logo.png" data-sticky="assets/images/logo-sticky.png">
```

and toggle the src attribute value with JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src',$('.navbar-brand img').data('sticky'));
    } else {
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src',$('.navbar-brand img').data('logo'))
    }   
});
```

to add logo in `src` on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src',$('.navbar-brand img').data('logo'));
});
```

jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nvpx2wky/).

Hope that helps :)